# SQL Server 2014 in memory table and transactions

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2014

I'm using Entity Framework 6.1.0 with SQL Server 2014.

I'm attempting to perform several operations under a transaction which i've created like this:

```
(var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
{


}
```

But I'm getting an error

> Accessing memory optimized tables using the READ COMMITTED isolation level is supported only for autocommit transactions. It is not supported for explicit or implicit transactions. Provide a supported isolation level for the memory optimized table using a table hint, such as WITH (SNAPSHOT).

I have tried all possible isolation levels (those allowed for in memory tables) but to no avail.

How can I perform atomic transactions from code with in memory tables?

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to enable MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_ELEVATE_TO_SNAPSHOT

Resource:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133175(v=sql.120).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133175%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)

Comment: More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21508173/in-memory-user-defined-table-not-in-memory